# how to calculate difference between two date when dates are extracted using formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I need a help to extract difference between two dates based on the cell reference provided. However, those cell reference given are extracted using the formula "=IF(A19="", "", IF(M19="Created", Timestamp(M19), TEXT(R19, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")))".
Where as Timestamp is the function code written in VBA script.

As an example:

cell value of R20 : "29/04/2021 12:56"
(extracted using the formula "IF(A20="", "", IF(M20="Created", Timestamp(M20), TEXT(R20, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")))"

cell value of T20: "30/04/2021 11:38"(extracted using the formula "=IF(A20="","",IF(M20="Resolved", Timestamp(M20), TEXT(U20, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")))"

Now in V20 I should get the difference between T20-R20, that should fetch in hh:mm format

But my error says "#Value#

Please suggest or help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can help much but you can try:

=INT((B10-B9)*24) & ":" & ROUND(((B10-B9)*24-INT((B10-B9)*24))*60,0)

Maybe there is a simpler way, but it worked for me!

It seems that your result has quotation marks. If so, then the formula in V20 won't work and you should change your VBA code to insert a date, not text.

Since you are already coding in VBA, you can also create another UDF to make this calculation.

Edit: I remembered you can use MOD to make a simpler formula like:

=INT((B10-B9)*24) & ":" & MOD((B10-B9)*24,1)*60

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it is not responding. For more details here is the VBA code which I have written

Comment: Function Timestamp(reference As Range)

If reference.Value <> "" Then

Timestamp = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")

End If

End Function

Comment: The above code is the function written for "Timestamp".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above query, my actual query is to enter the timestamp whenever I select the list from the data validation from the respective cell. However based on the selection/change of the item from the list, the timestamp should remain static, and it should not get changed when I save the worksheet.

Even I tried disabling "Enable iterative calculation" but as soon I save the worksheet the the date and time will get changed.